# do account in mongodb's admin database take precedence over accounts in "normal" databases

Tags: mongodb, user-roles

Just a quick question re user accounts in mongodb.

I have the following user configured in the admin database:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.system.users.find({ user : "foobar_admin"}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52024f53e513b080573d59de"),
        "otherDBRoles" : {
                "test" : [
                        "dbAdmin",
                        "readWrite"
                ]
        },
        "pwd" : "<pwdhash>",
        "roles" : [
                "read"
        ],
        "user" : "foobar_admin"
}
>
```

and the following user configured on the test database

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.system.users.find({ user : "abc_admin"}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52024f97e513b080573d59e1"),
        "pwd" : "<pwdhash>",
        "roles" : [
                "readWrite"
        ],
        "user" : "foobar_admin"
}
>
```

Do the permissions set in the admin database override those set in the test database? IE, does the foobar_admin have dbAdmin and readWrite on the test database? does one document have precedence over the other?

Comment: The best way is to test but I do remember reading something in the documentation about the admin user taking over the same user of that name in the local database. I personally have never had this ambiguity between my users, I try to avoid it

Comment: Yeah, i've inherited something that appears to have user documents in each db, so i am in the process of cleaning it all up. I am just a little cautious, as the db is currently in production, and cant afford to have it broken... Ill do some testing on one of my test boxes and see what i come up with.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, neither credentials take precedence, rather - the relevant roles are applied depending on which db the user authenticated to.

So in the above example,

- if the `foobar_admin` user authenticated against the `admin` database, the user would have the `dbAdmin` and `readWrite` roles
- if the `foobar_admin` user authenticated against the `test` database the user would only have the `readWrite` role

The documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/) doesn't appear to state this clearly.

Thanks for putting up with my ramblings! :)